# Forgot password or remove sda5_crypt password

Tags: 16.04, password, cryptsetup

I totally forgot my password and having no backups and all, is there a way to unlock this one?

[image: screenshot attached]

or if I have no choice, I just want to get the files or create a backup.

Already tried cloning but still required to encrypt. Please help.

Comment: Pretty sure it is possible to recover the system but not the data... This will require  the use of single user mode and physical access to the machine... Good Luck :)

Comment: Thank you @NerdOfCode, but this is build from virtual machine so its not possible to replace the machine physically. or is there way to change it virtually?

Comment: Are you looking to recover the data or just the system?

Comment: Hoping to recover the data

Comment: Good luck. I don't feel like its possible at this time.